# How to execute selenium java class files one by one using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on selenium-java code. i want to execute scripts of selenium java classes one by one using eclipse
for example : i have signup class first and email verification class second
currently i am running code manually means running first class file after that second
i want to execute that file automatically one after another
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing testing framework like jUnit / testNg.
Using such framework will allow you to run specific tests, test suites, test classes etc. in desired  order and priority, to enable / disable wanted / unwanted tests / test suites etc.